# How can I extract the Protein distance map data in Julia?

Tags: proteins, protein-protein-interaction

I calculated the distance between C-alphas using Julia,
but there is no way to extract distance map data from Julia.
I don't even know the data file form, png or csv or etc.
I don't want to extract it as an image, I just want all raw data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post an example of your input data, some code, any idea what your inputs and desired outputs are supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1):

for someone who have same question as mine...
this helps you to extract distance map data file.

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> writedlm("calphadistances.out",dm.data,"")
```